# Still getting download prompt with selenium after setting right MIME-type

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\path\\to\\the\\profile\\rust_mozprofile9nHEUU')

profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', '"application/pdf":{"action":0,"extensions":["pdf"]')

browser.get("https://amtsblatt.ag.ch/publikationen/")

elem = browser.find_element_by_id("pdf-select-all")
elem.click()
sleep(5)

elem2 = browser.find_element_by_class_name("pdf-list-head")
elem2.click()
sleep(5)

elem3 = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Exportieren")
elem3.click()
```

I want to get rid of the save/open-prompt when downloading a pdf-file from a website using selenium and firefox. I specifically looked up the right MIMEtype after accessing the site manually and downloading the pdf and put it as the 2nd argument with `profile.set_preference`. However, I still do get the save/open-prompt and am completely lost. Where did I go wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.